# Reporting Services 2008 sending SQL Authentication credentials even when told not to

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, windows-authentication

I have a SQL Reporting Services instance that has a couple of reports with a data source that's configured to use stored credentials. I checked the "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source" option, but the user still isn't logging in. I found an error in the event viewer telling me that the credentials used were SQL Authentication, so the login failed because the Database Engine instance only accepts Windows Auth.

Any clue what I might be missing, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to restart the Reporting Services services via the Services MMC plug-in. Didn't pick up the data source changes until I did this.

Comment: Interesting the service restart required. You should mark your own response as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, it was strange to me as well. I never had to before... And thanks for the reminder. Gotta wait 2 days and all...